# Using the Pascal PMF of order $k$

Tags: probability

Here's a homework question:

> A coin's probability to land on H is $p$. We toss it until we get the same
>       result as we did the first time. Let $X$ be the number of times we tossed
>       the coin.
>
> What is the expected value of $X$?

Okay so first I have to define the probability mass function (PMF) of $X$, right?
My problem is - how do I take into account the result of the first toss?

Also - I read a little and found out about the Pascal PMF of order $k$, which seems suitable for my case. Should I use it?

Comment: Hint: Consider the hypotheses of the first result and apply the formula of total probability. To calculate pmf of $X$ you may better calculate the pmf of the event that $X$ has not occur in $n$ steps.

Answer (score 1):

We give two fairly full solutions. The first involves finding the probability distribution of $X$. The second bypasses that, and works directly with expectations.  With either approach, it is a good idea to separate out the trivial cases $p=0$ and $p=1$.

**Analysis via the distribution function:** If you really want the distribution function of $X$, break things up into cases. It is clear that if $n<2$, then $P(X=n)=0$.

*Given* that at first you get a head (probability $p$) then the probability that $X=n$ is computed as follows. You need your initial head to be followed by $n-2$ tails, and then a head. This has probability $(1-p)^{n-2}p$.

*Given* that at first you get a tail (probability $1-p$) then the probability that $X=n$ is computed as follows. You need your initial tail to be followed by $n-2$ heads, and then a tail. This has probability $p^{n-2}(1-p)$.

Put things together. We get
$$P(X=n)=p(1-p)^{n-2}p +(1-p)p^{n-2}(1-p).$$
This can be simplified a bit. Not much.

To compute $E(X)$ from the probability distribution of $X$, note that
$$E(X)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n\left[p(1-p)^{n-2}p +(1-p)p^{n-2}(1-p)\right].$$
You can now find simplify by handling separately
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n p(1-p)^{n-2}p$$
and the other half.  These two sums are closely related to the sums you need to evaluate when you find the mean of a random variable that has **geometric** distribution. It is likely that the mean of the geometric distribution has already been done in your course.

**Direct calculation of expectation:** Either you first get a head (probability $p$) or a tail (probability $1-p$). Either way, it has cost you $1$ toss.

*Given* that you got a head, we now are waiting for another head.  The mean waiting time for a success where the probability of success is $p$ is $\dfrac{1}{p}$. (This comes from information about the *geometric* distribution, which likely has been dealt with in your course.)

*Given* that you got a tail, we now are waiting for another tail.  The mean waiting time for a success where the probability of success is $1-p$ is $\dfrac{1}{1-p}$.
It follows that 
$$E(X)=1+p\frac{1}{p}+(1-p)\frac{1}{1-p}=3.$$
Please note that the above analysis *does not work* if $p=0$ or $p=1$. In those two cases (with probability $1$), the game last for $2$ tosses only, and therefore $E(X)=2$.

Comment: Can you please explain what formula you were using on the second part? You've multiplied P(X=x) with its expected value and I haven't seen it done before, even though it makes perfectly sense. Also, why is the 1 there at the beginning? Thanks

Comment: The $1$ is for the first toss.  After the first toss we are in one of two geometric distributions. I was using the formula for the mean of a geometric random variable, plus the Law of Total Expectation, which involves *conditional expectation*. An unfancy version: if $A$ is an event, and $A'$ is the complement of $A$, then $E(X)=E(X|A)P(A)+E(X|A')P(A')$.  Imagine choosing game $G$ with prob. $p$, $H$ with prob. $1-p$. If expected losses for the games are resp. $g$, $h$, then for hybrid game expected loss is $pg+(1-p)h$.

Comment: A third way, which one could call intermediary, is first to compute $P(X\geqslant n)$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and then to use the fact that these sum to $E(X)$.